# Scheme - Convert boolean to string?

Tags: scheme, boolean, racket

I am having a tough time trying to find an example of converting a boolean to a string in Scheme.

My problem is that I use string-append to add a few strings together as part of a debugger. 
My fix was to check if equal to #t, then append "#t", and like-wise with #f.

My question- is there a method in Scheme to convert bools to strings? Something like bool->string?

My Code:

```
(if (equal? val #t)
                       (string-append (number->string count) ":" "#t")    
                       (string-append (number->string count) ":" "#f")    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `format`:

```
> (format "~a" #t)
"#t"
> (format "~a" #f)
"#f"
```

Comment: In the latest version of Racket (5.3.1), you can also use the `~a` function: `(~a #t)`. You'll need to `(require racket/format)`.

Comment: Very nice, I forgot that `format` already does the implicit string port thing.

Answer (score 4):

This might help you:

```
(define (->string x)
  (call-with-output-string
   (lambda (out)
     (display x out))))
```

This writes out *any* object to a string port and returns its string value.

```
> (->string #t)
"#t"
> (->string #f)
"#f"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(define (boolean-to-string val) (if val "#t" "#f"))

(string-append (number->string count) ":" (boolean-to-string val))
```